# Best approach for performing multiple condition on row in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, iteration, performancecounter

Which is the best approach while doing the row wise operation with lot of conditions in the PySpark's Dataframe?

For example, let's consider the below one,

**Method 1:**

```
def fn(row):
  row = row.asDict()

  if row['col_A'] != row['col_B']:
     row['col_C'] = 'some value'
  elif row['col_B'] != row['col_C']:
     row['col_D'] = 'some other value'

  ....  ....  ....
  ....  ....  ....
  if row['col_Z'].strip() not in ('A', 'B')
     row['col_A'] = 'OK'

  ....  ....  ....
  ....  ....  ....
  return Row(**row)

df = df.rdd.map(fn)
```

**Method 2:**

```
 df = df.withColumn('col_C', F.when(F.col('col_A') != F.col('col_B')))\
        .withColumn('col_D', F.when(F.col('col_B') != F.col('col_C')))\
        .withColumn('col_E', F.when(F.col('col_C') != F.col('col_D')))\
        .withColumn('col_F', F.when(F.col('col_D') != F.col('col_E')))\
        .withColumn('col_G', F.when(F.col('col_E') != F.col('col_F')))\
        .withColumn('col_H', F.when(F.col('col_F') != F.col('col_G')))\
        ....  ....  ....
        ....  ....  ....
        .withColumn('col_Y', F.when(F.col('col_W') != F.col('col_X')))\
        .withColumn('col_Z', F.when(F.col('col_X') != F.col('col_Y')))
```

I think, UDF functions (Method 2) is always a better approach, But it's still true for the above situation as well?

How it will work an internally?.. I think, In the "Method 1" it will iterate an each row by maximum only one time and in the "Method 2" it will iterate the whole dataframe for an each **small** if condition/withColumn method..?

For example, If the dataframe has `n` rows then iterate,

Method 1 => `n` times only

Method 2 => `n * no_of_withColumn()` method

Which method is always best regardless of the count of rows & the no. of filter conditions are used internally.

Comment: You can try using `df.explain` in order to view the plan, which may depend on the number of rows in the DataFrame.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain

Comment: @ELinda Thanks, I will check.